# Content exceeds Flexbox limits using media queries! Any Solutions?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

Like the title said, the content in the flexbox i am using exceeds the limits when using media queries.

Let me explain it to you:

I'm designing as an exercise some responsive content blocks, which change from being side by side to being on top of each other when the maximum screen width is 850px. For this, I have used media queries as I have been learning.

Now, when the media query makes the changes in the code, both the margins of both divs, as well as their paddings are altered and misplaced, making them uneven, which then using the developer tools, marks how the divs exceed the edge of the Flexbox and their margins are disunirformed.

Here's my code, both HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta lang="en">
        <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <title>Test Area</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="principal">
                <h1>Principal</h1>
                <p>Culpa sint qui exercitation occaecat nulla sunt excepteur sunt eiusmod Lorem dolore ullamco minim. Elit deserunt dolor reprehenderit reprehenderit id excepteur sunt Lorem et nulla labore officia sit proident. Occaecat nostrud esse in anim dolore. Esse culpa mollit officia nulla sunt fugiat deserunt irure. Lorem ipsum occaecat laboris officia et cillum dolor aute. Proident aute pariatur sit dolor irure sint nostrud ut et aliquip ex.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="secondary">
                <h2>Secondary</h2>
                <p>Laborum et id dolor sit qui nulla laborum adipisicing nulla veniam aliqua ut ipsum. Laborum veniam consequat aliqua esse. Ea velit velit et proident do mollit aliquip esse Lorem officia. Dolore elit sit sint aliqua laborum velit cillum quis. Velit adipisicing ut consectetur occaecat. Non voluptate ad nisi enim ut voluptate ullamco nostrud aute.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;500;600&display=swap');

/* General Styles Preset */

body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

h1, h2{
    font-size: 28px;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
}

.principal{
    background-color: aquamarine;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 60%;

    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.secondary{
    background-color: cadetblue;
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 40%;

    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .principal, .secondary{
        flex: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**Here's some images to what it looks like when using dev tools:**

[image: Both divs width exceed the flexbox limits]

[image: It looks displaced and disuniform]

**What have i tried?**

I have tried to look for solutions in YouTube, Stack overflow, and artificial intelligence, but sadly I have not found any answer that solves my problem, neither I have found questions that are related to mine here in overflow.

**What do i want it to do?**

Basically, I just want that, when the maximum screen width is 850 pixels, the blocks, instead of being side by side, are on top of each other. The idea is to respect the 60%/40% width of both blocks on screens wider than 850 pixels.

In addition, it is obvious to point out that the idea is that when the media query is activated, margins and paddings are kept uniform, orderly and even.

I hope i was able to explain it all, I'm gonna edit this question as needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than putting margins on your blocks, set a `gap` on the flex container. That will make sure your flex items (blocks) all stay a consistent distance apart regardless of how they get arranged or rearranged.

```
.container {
  gap: 10px;
}
```

It’s also considered best-practice to do **mobile-first** design, which means the base styles in your CSS should be the narrow screen styles, then add media queries for wider screens in increasing order of width. In this snippet I have rearranged the CSS to be mobile-first.

After running this snippet, make sure to use the **full page** link to test the responsive behaviour.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;500;600&display=swap');

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.principal, .secondary {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

.principal>*:first-child, .secondary>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.principal>*:last-child, .secondary>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.principal {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.secondary {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

@media (min-width: 850px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .principal {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .secondary {
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="principal">
    <h1>Principal</h1>
    <p>Culpa sint qui exercitation occaecat nulla sunt excepteur sunt eiusmod Lorem dolore ullamco minim. Elit deserunt dolor reprehenderit reprehenderit id excepteur sunt Lorem et nulla labore officia sit proident. Occaecat nostrud esse in anim dolore. Esse culpa mollit officia nulla sunt fugiat deserunt irure. Lorem ipsum occaecat laboris officia et cillum dolor aute. Proident aute pariatur sit dolor irure sint nostrud ut et aliquip ex.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">
    <h2>Secondary</h2>
    <p>Laborum et id dolor sit qui nulla laborum adipisicing nulla veniam aliqua ut ipsum. Laborum veniam consequat aliqua esse. Ea velit velit et proident do mollit aliquip esse Lorem officia. Dolore elit sit sint aliqua laborum velit cillum quis. Velit adipisicing ut consectetur occaecat. Non voluptate ad nisi enim ut voluptate ullamco nostrud aute.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

After running this snippet, make sure to use the **full page** link to test the responsive behaviour.

Comment: Why do you use  >*:first-child and >*last-child? What does it that for? I would appreciate it if you could explain briefly how it works in this case, so that I can learn it.

Comment: These declarations remove the top margin from the first content item of each block, and the bottom margin from the last content item. This way, the space between the four edges of the block and the edges of the content inside the block are entirely comprised of the padding defined on the block. It means you get consistent space on all four sides. If you comment these rules, or disable them in your browser inspector, you’ll see that results in too much space inside the top and bottom of each block.